# Is Yahoo Directory Worth It?

Tags: directory, yahoo

Is Yahoo Directory worth the $299? Will it generate any traffic?

I've got a Flex 3 site, so unfortunately, I'm invisible in SEO terms. I was wondering if signing up for this would help.

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Might want to try this on the webmasters stack exchange.

Comment: This is both a subjective question, and further has little to do with the programming-related topics of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. I'll try on webmasters stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yahoo Directory in general is worth it.  It should give your SERP by at least 10-20%. Flex 3 site could contain text that Google finds.  They've been considering text in Flash for a while.  You may want to add some meta text somewhere on the page so Google can see more prominent relevance to your search term.  Key to success: Blog and write good content pointing back to your site.  Write quality content on your site itself.